# Firebase Error when Downloading Images

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I list images in `RecyclerView`(Grid layout) from Firebase, and sometimes everything works ok, but sometimes I get this errors :

```
W/StorageTask: unable to change internal state to: INTERNAL_STATE_IN_PROGRESS isUser: false from state:INTERNAL_STATE_CANCELING
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                The operation was cancelled.
                Code: -13040 HttpResult: 0
```

In start images are listing fine,but after few scrolling,this error starting and images randomly not downloaded..How to fix that?

I'm using `com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1` and `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.0`

Comment: Did you try with `android:largeHeap` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as an attribute in your application tag?

Comment: Yes i try,and nothing change..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error uploading the image on firebase.

The error was produced because the firebase auth version and storage/database version did not match in app/build.gradle file.